# maximum likelihood pdf

Tags: econometrics, estimation, parameter-estimation

I am looking at the topic maximum likelihood, and I cannot understand why we set the pdf of $y_{t}$ equal to 1. It is with regards to a OLS example.

The information i got is this:

Model: $y_{t}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1} x_{1, t}+\beta_{2} x_{2, t}+u_{t}$ where $u_{t} \sim N\left(0, \sigma^{2}\right)$

We want to estimate the parameter $\theta=\left\{\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}, \beta_{2}, \sigma^{2}\right\}$

The PDF of $u_{t}$ = $f\left(y_{t}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2}}} \exp \left[-\frac{\left(u_{t}\right)^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}\right]$

We thus get that PDF of $y_{t}$ is: $f\left(y_{t}\right)=f\left(u_{t}\right)\left|\frac{\partial u_{t}}{\partial y_{t}}\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2}}} \exp \left[-\frac{\left(y_{t}-\beta_{0}-\beta_{1} x_{1, t}-\beta_{2} x_{2, t}\right)}{2 \sigma^{2}}\right]$

Where we use $\frac{\partial u_{t}}{\partial y_{t}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{t}}\left[y_{t}-\beta_{0}-\beta_{1} x_{1, t}-\beta_{2} x_{2, t}\right]=1$

I dont understand why this equals 1, do we just set it equal to 1?

Comment: Shouldn't you be taking the derivative of the pdf of y and setting that equal to zero?

Comment: Also the way i thought, and when i have done that, i should be able to solve for the maximum likelihood. Thats why i do not understand why they want me to set it equal to 1

Comment: Beta_0, beta_1, and beta_2 all have no dependence on y so they will contribute zero terms to the derivative and then the derivative of y wtr y is ofc 1 so you will get one for du/dy. But I don't see how that step is helpful for mle.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33659/difference-between-sum-of-squares-and-maximum-likelihood-linear-regression/33677#33677
maybe it clears some things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

$y_t$ is independent from $x_{1,t}$ and $x_{2,t}$ by definition, otherwise $u_t$ should be deterministic.

It means that $\frac{dx_{1,t}}{dy_t}=0$ and $\frac{dx_{2,t}}{dy_t}=0$. All betas are constant so $\frac{du_t}{dy_t}=1$.

Comment: Right. The derivative of u wrt y would be 1. But that isn't what he would need if he was trying to maximize the likelihood?

Comment: @roz: The OP needs the jacobian in order to go from the density of the $u_t$ to the density of $y_t$.

Answer (score 0):

Because u = y - b0 - b1x1 - b2x2, by definition. So any derivatives must surely follow from this...

I suspect your problem here lies in the econometric distinction of “reality” where the above holds true; versus the model, where you are estimating betas and hoping normally-distributed residuals etc.

Seen thus, changing actual-Y will also change your residual by 1 times this - given any current model. And thus your model error, given the equivalence above.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are overthinking it.

If $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+u$ note that a 1 unit increase in $u$ results in a 1 unit increase in $y$.  The same is true for a two unit causing a two unit change or negative seven unit change causing a negative seven unit change.  That is also true in the opposite direction.

$u=y-\beta_0-\beta_1x_1-\beta_2x_2$

Neither $x_1$ nor $x_2$ are a function of $y$, so $$\frac{\partial{}u}{\partial{y}}=1-0-0-0$$

The derivative of $y$ with respect to $y$ is one.